# Netbeans platform simple window communication

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-platform

I'm currently using the Netbeans platform and can't seem to get one TopComponent to communicate with another. My research has pointed me in the direction of using Lookups however I can't seem to access my function.

I have one `TopComponent` called `AppleTopComponent`, which has a method called `myName()` and I want to call it from my `OrangeTopComponent`, which is called within a button handler, inside that handler I have the following code.

```
TopComponent tc = WindowManager.getDefault().findTopComponent("AppleTopComponent");
Lookup tcLookup = tc.getLookup();
tcLookip.myName();
```

Surely this should be a simple process, what is it I'm doing wrong.

Many thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you're looking for.

```
    TopComponent tc = WindowManager.getDefault().findTopComponent("AppleTopComponent");
    AppleTopComponent atc = (AppleTopComponent) tc;
    jLabel1.setText(atc.myName());
```